# jQuery's parseJSON from HTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get an error when trying to parse JSON from a HTML data attribute. This is the `div` I want to parse JSON from:

```
echo '<div class="udropdown" data-elements=\'{"option1" : "1", "option2" : "2" }\'></div>';
```

and this is the jQuery part (it's on click, so `$(this)` is necessary)

```
var ele = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data('elements'));
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: shouldn't need to use `parseJSON()` since `data()` will do the parsing internally

Comment: But either way, if you are returning HTML, why not return the options already? What's the point of having a data attribute with JSON in it?

Comment: @AndréSilva lots of possible use cases, for example initialize a plugin

Comment: @charlietfl This seems not to be the case.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation for `jQuery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

`$(this).data('elements')` will have parsed the JSON in the string to an object already.

`jQuery.parseJSON(object)` is equivalent to `jQuery.parseJSON(object.toString())` which gives you `jQuery.parseJSON("[object Object")`.

Just skip the manual `parseJSON` step. jQuery has already done it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you already have a parsed object there. In this case `parseJSON` tries to treat your input as a string and as long as it is already an object it will be treated as the following string:

```
[object Object]
```

or similar. It thinks then that symbol `[` is a beginning of some array (which is still a valid JSON) and `o` is exactly what it does not expect to get there because it either must be a number, boolean, or one of those symbols `'`, `"` or `{`.

Just check the data type of `$(this).data('elements')` - it must be an object.

Try the following:

```
JSON.parse({})
```

that will return exactly the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).data('elements')` return an object so you don't have to parse anything just use the `ele` returned, e.g :

```js
$('.udropdown').click(function(){
    var ele = $(this).data('elements');
    console.log(ele.option1, ele.option2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="udropdown" data-elements='{"option1" : "1", "option2" : "2" }'>Click HERE</div>
```